# Como alterar a cor da barra de progresso?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

Eu gostaria de fazer duas coisas na minha barra de progresso.

- Mudar a cor de verde para vermelho.
- Remover os blocos e criar uma cor.

Estou usando o  Visual Studio Community 2019 no Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Como Fazer

Primeiro, inclua isto se você não tiver:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Segundo, você pode criar uma nova classe ou colocar seu código em uma `static class` não genérica existente:

```
public static class ModificarCorProgressBar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr w, IntPtr l);
    public static void SetState(this ProgressBar pBar, int state)
    {
        SendMessage(pBar.Handle, 1040, (IntPtr)state, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Como foi criado um método de extensão `SetState` podemos chama-lo diretamente desta forma:

```
progressBar1.SetState(2)
```

Lembrando que o segundo parâmetro em `SetState`:

> **1** = normal (verde)
> **2** = erro (vermelho)
> **3** = aviso (amarelo)

## Resultados da Amostra

Utilizando o Windows 8 ou superior com esse método a seguir, você pode obter algo assim:

[image: teste no Win8/10]

Já no Windows Vista e Windows 7 o resultado vai ser um pouco diferente (sinceramente até melhor)

[image: teste no WinVista/7]

> Esta é uma adaptação da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753302/11294882) dada por [user1032613](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032613/user1032613) no SO .